# Same methods with different return types

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two methods almost same in body but different in return type. One is IEnumerator and another is void . Is there any Smart way of writing code so that I have to write less lines of code.

```
IEnumerator CreatePath(int val)
{
        if (val < worlds.Length - 1) {
                int totalChild = CountChildren (Path [val].transform);
                MeshRenderer[] child = Path [val].transform.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer> ();

                for (int i = 0; i < totalChild; i++) {
                        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.2f);

                        child [i].enabled = true;   
                }
        }

}
```

And

```
void CreatePath_(int val)
{
        if (val < worlds.Length - 1) {
                int totalChild = CountChildren (Path [val].transform);
                MeshRenderer[] child = Path [val].transform.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer> ();

                for (int i = 0; i < totalChild; i++) {
                        child [i].enabled = true;   
                }
        }
}
```

And the whole script

```
public GameObject[] worlds,Path;
public  int ClearedWorldValue = -1;
private int posArray;

void Start()
{
    SetMapState ();
}

void SetMapState()
{
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                ChangeColor (i,0);

        }

}

void ChangeColor(int val,float pause){
        if (val!=-1) {
            worlds [val].transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
            worlds [val].transform.GetChild (1).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;  
                StartCoroutine (CreatePath (val, pause));
                ChangeColortoRed (val);
        }

}

void ChangeColortoRed(int val)
{
        if (val < worlds.Length-1) {
                worlds [val + 1].transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().enabled = true;
        }
}

IEnumerator CreatePath(int val,float pause)
{
        if (val < worlds.Length - 1) {
                int totalChild = CountChildren (Path [val].transform);
                MeshRenderer[] child = Path [val].transform.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer> ();

                for (int i = 0; i < totalChild; i++) {
                        yield return new WaitForSeconds (pause);

                        child [i].enabled = true;   
                }
        }

}



int CountChildren(Transform a)
{
        int childCount = 0;
        foreach (Transform b in a)
        {
            childCount ++;
            childCount += CountChildren (b);
        }
        return childCount;
}

void Update()
{
    ChangeColor (ClearedWorldValue,0.2f);
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between this two methods beside return type?

Comment: how does void return a type?

Comment: Try posting a little bit more details and the related part of your code if possible.

Comment: Use CreatePath for both calls. Ignore the return value when you don't need it.

Comment: @ChuckSavage The problem is that first one works much slower, due to `yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.2f);`

Comment: Then use an additional argument variable, such as `bool useyield = true`, then put a check in there.

Comment: Can I use  yield return null instead of creating another method

Comment: @Valentin I am new in this field so I am thinking about some way of code where I don't have to repeat the lines. and this code is working fine .

Answer (score 1):

you can either make it generic or return object.
The best is to extract the repeating part in a separate method.

Comment: These are my two methos

Answer (score 0):

Methods have quite different behavior, because `IEnumerator` one has `WaitForSeconds` inside, so you can add a new parameter `pause` to the method with default value, which will be equal to pause duration.

```
IEnumerator CreatePath(int val, float pause = 0)
{
        if (val < worlds.Length - 1) {
                int totalChild = CountChildren (Path [val].transform);
                MeshRenderer[] child = Path [val].transform.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer> ();

                for (int i = 0; i < totalChild; i++) {
                        yield return new WaitForSeconds (pause);

                        child [i].enabled = true;   
                }
        }

}
```

Then you can use `CreatePath (1)` method without pause(or with default pause) or `CreatePath(1, 100)` with specified pause duration.

But I suggest to split it to three methods, one base method and two that will call the base method, with different params, so your method name will represent a behavior of a method.

```
IEnumerator CreatePathWithPause(int val, float pause)
{
        if (val < worlds.Length - 1) {
                int totalChild = CountChildren (Path [val].transform);
                MeshRenderer[] child = Path [val].transform.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer> ();

                for (int i = 0; i < totalChild; i++) {
                        yield return new WaitForSeconds (pause);

                        child [i].enabled = true;   
                }
        }

}

IEnumerator CreatePath(int val) 
{
    return CreatePathWithPause(val, 0)
}

IEnumerator CreatePathWithDefaultPause(int val) 
{
    return CreatePathWithPause(val, 0.2f)
}
```

Comment: Its still taking some time to Create Path when I am using Co-Routine even if I put zero in wait time

Comment: Which method are you using?